# How do I get Google Play for Android 6/Marshmallow to Work on Visual Studio Android Emulator?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've downloaded and installed Visual Studio Android Emulator and think it's very good - faster to start up than even Genymotion but I'm trying to test my app on Marshmallow/Android 6 but cannot find a gapps zip file for Android 6 to work on the microsoft emulator. Any ideas?

Thanks,

T

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense? If you have the latest version of the visual studio emulator installed it should have predefined profiles available for android 6.0 to download and install?

Comment: It has predefined profiles for Android 6 Phil bit not one for Android 6 with Google Apps and Play store. I need one with a least Google Play services so I can try some in-app purchases on Android 6

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Google Play Services will install on Marshmallow emulators but they won't run and there is no option to add a Google account when going to Settings > Accounts > Add Account.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to install gapps on Marshmallow emulator.

Here's compact guide (followed by one of the links found on net, sadly didn't save a link).

Follow this steps (I've recreated device prior install):

1. Install ARM Translation Installer v1.1 (http://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/0ZIO8PME/Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip_links) and restart device.
2. Install Google Apps for Android 5.1 (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=96042739161891406 - gapps-L-4-21-15.zip), yep, gapps for 5.1.
3. **Login into your google account!!!**
4. Install Google Apps for Android 6.0 (https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24052804347835438 - benzo-gapps-M-20151011-signed-chroma-r3.zip)

After this steps I successfully tested my app, required google play services.

P.S. Seems that method requires install of Google Calendar to use calendar functions (like insert or access calendar records), but I'm not sure in this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The main thing that help me was able to create google account by installing the 5.1 first.

Comment: All these are zip files, not an APK. How you suppose to install them?